# API Steam - Account not found

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

How is possibile when I try to take data in XML API Steam, from [my account](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Askancy?xml=1) works: 
but if I try to get data from [another account](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Giogio993?xml=1) doesn't work?

```
<response>
<error>
<![CDATA[ The specified profile could not be found. ]]>
</error>
</response>
```

In addition, when a user has got a symbols or space in the name, how become the link for API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User doesn't have custom url "giogio993" associated with his profile. It means that he has user page http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198089474071 but it can't be accessed via link http://steamcommunity.com/id/giogio993 unlike your http://steamcommunity.com/id/Askancy

As for spaces in name - I don't think steam allows this. Just try changing your own name and see what happens.

**UPDATE**

Also, you can check this account with steamrep:
http://steamrep.com/search?q=76561198089474071

As you see, field "Custom URL" is just empty.

As for your profile:
http://steamrep.com/search?q=Askancy

Custom URL is okay.
The real question is "how to get user info from account without vanity URL". I did not find an answer to this question yet.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how Steam vanity URLs work -- usernames are totally separate from them. /id/giogio993 just doesn't map to anything.

Comment: @Fiskie Of cause those are separate entities. But for most sane users those should be equal - that's why I checked link with id/giogio993 - to prove that the problem lies within user, not within API. The problem is that mentioned user just doesn't have custom URL.

Comment: You are claiming something is wrong with the account, which is incorrect. Bans do nothing to vanity URLs.

Comment: @Fiskie if user has no friendly URL - there is certainly something wrong with his account - at least since it became unaccessable with API.

Comment: Users do not have vanity URLs until they create one. You can see this for yourself, accounts with vanity URLs will redirect from community ID lookups. Compare http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198012598620 and http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198012598621

Comment: @Fiskie Yeah, my mistake. then the real question is "how to get user info from account without vanity URL". I didn't find an answer yet.

Comment: My answer contains information about that (plus you probably want to be using the JSON WebAPIs over XML anyway)

Comment: @Fiskie I don't see that information in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple -- there is [no account using this vanity URL](http://steamcommunity.com/id/giogio993). This is not a bug of any sort.

> when a user has got a symbols or space in the name, how become the link for API?

Vanity URLs can only take alphanumeric characters (and possibly underscores), so you don't need to worry about special characters. You can also access user XML associated with a community ID via [the /profiles/ URL](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198012598620?xml=1), which might be preferable over mutable vanity URLs.